# Bash file that creates a directory and subdirectories

Tags: linux, bash

I'm new to Bash and have a little program that asks for an input between 1 and 10 and then proceeds to create the same amount of directories the user typed. At the moment my program creates all of the directories in one location, so I'm wondering if there's a way I can create a main folder and then the subdirectories inside one another.

For example:

```
How many directories would you like to create?

user input: 3

folder1    
      |-folder2    
              |-folder3
```

Any tips on how to get my program to do this will be very much appreciated.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
read -p "How many directories would you like?" num_folder
if test $num_folder -lt 10
then
    for ((i=0; i<num_folder; i++)); do
      mkdir folder$i        
    done

    tree -c

    read -rsp "Press enter to continue"
    clear

else
    echo "Please write a number between 1 and 10"      
fi
```

Comment: Do `cd folder$i` after `mkdir folder$i` in the loop

Comment: Oh, my goodness. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Another solution maybe the usage of `-p` parameter with `mkdir`.

```
mkdir -p "$(seq -f "folder%0.0f" -s "/" $num_folder)"
```

Comment: `seq` is not defined in POSIX but the question is tagged `bash` so you can use something like `$(eval printf "folder%s/" {1..$num_folder})`

Comment: @tripleee Thank you for telling me this way of brace expansion.

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
seq 1 3 | xargs mkdir
```

you can simply use numbers.